# Buffer Explorer for vim

Tags: vim

What do people recommend for easier manipulation of buffers in vim?

Using ls and b1, bn and bp commands is good but maybe there is a better way.

Is lusty explorer the best option?

I am using vim 7.3.

Comment: I'm surprised this has survived trigger happy 10k+'s flagging this as controversial / opinionated ... etc.

Answer (score 27):

You should test all of them and see which one is the best according to your tastes and requirements.

I've used [LustyExplorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1890) for a while and loved it until I tried [CtrlP](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3736) which I *find* faster and more intuitive. I have `:CtrlPBuffer` mapped to `,b` and see no reason to complain: it's both elegant, fast and intuitive.

You don't have to rely on plugins, though: `:b <tab>` allows you to tab through a list of all available buffers. You can do `:b pattern<Tab>` to get a smaller list.

Comment: I cannot agree more with the first statement; there is lots out there and it's really very subjective, so it really depends on your taste. Figure out a good system to easily switch plugins (Vundle/Pathogen/VAM) and then try out the plugins until you've found a setup that works well for _you_.

Comment: i would like to use  `:CtrlPBuffer` because Ialready installed CtrlP, BUT CtrlP do not list ALL buffers... just a subset. Any idea why ? Viceversa I like to map `:buffer <Tab><Tab>` (to Ctrl-A) inserting in .vimrc: `nnoremap <C-A> :buffer <TAB><TAB>` but I'm wrong something because I do not raech the expected behaviour..

Comment: I map :CtrlPBuffer to C-a, now switch between 2 buffers (which is a high frequency action) is simply C-a<CR>.

Comment: `:b <tab>` is very simple, when you keep navigating source code and often need to switch between previous and current file, then open another etc etc you need something that remembers previous buffer and let you switch easilly

Comment: To switch between two buffers already has the built-in keybind `,,` (presumably that's actually `<leader>,` or `<leader><leader>`)

Comment: ```:b <tab>``` ah that;s an epiphany, never thought of that!

Answer (score 8):

[Unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) is a new plugin and is what I switched to from CtrlP.

[This](http://bling.github.io/blog/2013/06/02/unite-dot-vim-the-plugin-you-didnt-know-you-need/) is a good starting point if you want to explore what it can do.

Answer (score 5):

I use [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159). I guess its main advantage is that it takes up very little space.

Answer (score 4):

FuzzyFinder is another excellent add-on for buffer/file navigation:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984

Whichever plugin you choose for this, it's worth investing some time to find out all the ways it can help you.

Comment: fuzzy find also has the feature that when you install the core fzf library, it (optionally) hooks into your shell to make ctrl-r (search history) a fuzzy-finding interactive experience in the terminal. I couldn't live without it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are fine with having vim compiled with ruby support and have dev toolchain installed on the system (make, gcc, maybe something else — Gentoo users like me already have all of this) then [Command-T](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) is a good choice. To use it for switching buffers you should map something to `:CommandTBuffer`, I have

```
nnoremap         ,b   :CommandTBuffer<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

I used many plugins before, including minibufexpl and Bufexplorer, but there was something in all of them that used to annoy me.

Now I use young plugin [Buffet](http://goo.gl/rdjgJ), and I would recommend it because it seems to be really the best one for me: it is really fast and easy to use.

Personally i would like to switch my buffers by <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, and buffers should be ordered in most-recently-used order.

Here is my buffet's config to achieve <kbd><C-Tab></kbd> and <kbd><S-C-Tab></kbd> switching:

```
noremap <silent> <C-Tab> :Bufferlistsw<CR>
noremap <silent> <C-S-Tab> :Bufferlistsw<CR>kk
if !has('gui')
   map <S-q> :Bufferlistsw<CR>
endif

augroup BuffetAdd
   if !exists("g:BuffetAdded")
      let g:BuffetAdded = 1
      au BufWinEnter buflisttempbuffer* map <buffer> <Tab> <CR>
      au BufWinEnter buflisttempbuffer* map <buffer> <C-Tab>   j
      au BufWinEnter buflisttempbuffer* map <buffer> <C-S-Tab> k

      " in console Vim we can't use <C-Tab> mappings (almost always),
      " so this is temporary solution: <S-q>
      if !has('gui')
         au BufWinEnter buflisttempbuffer* map <buffer> <S-q> j
         au BufWinEnter buflisttempbuffer* map <buffer> q <CR>
      endif

      " workaround Surround plugin issue in Buffet's window:
      " disable "ds" mapping in the Buffet window (to make "d" work fast)
      au BufEnter buflisttempbuffer* nunmap ds
      au BufLeave buflisttempbuffer* nmap   ds <Plug>Dsurround

   endif
augroup END
```

Just one issue: Vim does not allow you to map *release* of some key, so, you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to really switch to buffer.

Anyway, if you don't need <kbd><C-Tab></kbd> switching, Buffet plugin works nice without it.

Comment: You have an error here: `has('gui')` checks whether vim was compiled with gui support, not whether you are using gui version of vim. It should be `has('gui_running')`.

Comment: @ZyX, thanks, you're right. But if I run console version of Vim (i.e. `vim` instead of `gvim`), then `has('gui')` returns `0` too.

Comment: It depends on the way vim was compiled. I can compile vim with one executable for both gui and console versions where `has('gui')` will return 1, in fact I *use* this for testing (doing compilation once is simpler).

Answer (score 1):

**Update June 2019**

[BufExplorer](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer) is my unequivocal first-choice for buffer management.

```
" Buffer explorer
" ,be to open, q to close, d to delete buffer
Plug 'jlanzarotta/bufexplorer'
```

Highly rate the above plugin. It's simple and effective. Further details in the [readme](https://github.com/jlanzarotta/bufexplorer/blob/master/doc/bufexplorer.txt).

If you're looking for some "extras" in addition to the above (optional), I do also use:

```
" Close buffers but keep splits
Plug 'moll/vim-bbye'
```

and:

```
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
" this setting for quick search across buffers
nmap <silent> <leader>b :Buffers<cr>
```